What Policy/Agent and Observation Spec To Use For TensorFlow Agents For Video Game Platformer?
I'm trying to create a model to beat a video game platformer I made a few months ago.  In the game, the platforms scroll down from the sky and the player has to keep jumping to them to avoid touching the ground.  The platforms scroll down faster and faster as the game progresses.
I've setup the environment and can run a training loop but the player can't seem to figure out how to jump up to the 4th platform and beyond.  They player can make it up the third platform though.
I've adjusted the rewards and let it train for over an hour with no results so I think it may be to policy or agent I'm using to train it with.
I also found when I added the platforms's X and Y to the observation spec, it made results worse. I think this is due to added complexity.
Here is a link to a web version of the game on itch.io
